# Error: Use the unresolved identifier 'indexPath' in prepareForSeque function

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am getting an two unresolved identifier errors in the following function.

// MARK: - Segues

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! {

            let selectedCity = cities?[indexPath.row]

            (segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController).city = selectedCity
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Xcode 7 and swift 2.0. Much appreciate any help.

Comment: You are missing a `let`:  `if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
{
}
```

to if using swift below 2.0,
because `indexPathForSelectedRow` is not a property its a method so use () at end, and it returns optional so you need to use `let` as well

```
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {

}
```

screenshot is from Xcode 6.4 [image]
For swift 2.0 don't use () at the end, as its a property

```
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

}
```

screen shot from Xcode 7.1
[image]

Comment: `indexPathForSelectedRow` is a property, not a function.

Comment: its a method you can check the header

Comment: @vacawama FYI - All properties are really methods (a getter and a setter (if not read-only)).

Comment: @vacawama I edited it with an image you should see that

Comment: In Swift 2.0, you need to access it like a property.

Comment: Yup agreed with, all properties are methods indeed@rmaddy

Comment: @vacawama underlying its a method

Comment: `error: invalid use of '()' to call a value of non-function type 'NSIndexPath?'`

Comment: as @rmaddy said all properties are methods (getter and setter , if readonly its getter only) and it will save its value to an ivar, so when we declare property it means we are adding getter setter method for an iVar, which is now in latest iOS sdk created automatically

Comment: @C_X BTW - In the iOS 9 docs, `indexPathForSelectedRow` is documented as a property, not as a method. Where is the little image you posted from?

Comment: Thank you very much for that C_X. That has helped a lot. Although, I have just run it and I have other errors in the app. It worked in Xcode 6 but now it won't run in Xcode 7. Will post errors in another post.

Comment: @rmaddy at that time I was working with xCode6.4 so that's why its like this.